# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f(x+y^3)=f(x)+f(y)^3$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f(x+y^3)=f(x)+f(y)^3$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f'(0)\ge0$, find $f(10)$.

If $x=y=0$, $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$. So $f(0)=0$.

If $x=0$, $f(0+y^3)=f(0)+f(y)^3$. So $f(y^3)=f(y)^3$.

So $f(x)=x^n$ or $f(x)=\mathrm{constant}$.

But I am not getting the given answer if $f(x)=x^n$.

Comment: How you conclude that $f(x)=x^n$ ?

Comment: $f(x^m)=(x^m)^n=x^{mn}=(x^n)^m=f(x)^m$

Comment: @AdityaDev it does not necessarily satisfy the original functional equation.

Comment: $f(x)=x^n$ doesn't satisfy the original identity. Neither does $f(x)=constant$ for that matter (except if the $constant=0$).

Comment: @dxiv or if $n=1$

Comment: I should have added "_in_ _general_". Yes $f(x)=x$ does work.

Comment: FYI: You can't conclude that $f(x) = x^n$ from just the identity $f(y^3) = f(y)^3$. For instance, the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}x^n & \text{if} \ x \ge 0 \\ x^m & \text{if} \ x < 0\end{cases}$ also satisfies the identity $f(y^3) = f(y)^3$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $f'(0)$ exists, we know that $f'(0) = \displaystyle\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{f(y)-f(0)}{y-0} = \lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{f(y)}{y}$ exists.

Then, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\dfrac{f(x+y^3)-f(x)}{y^3} = \dfrac{f(y)^3}{y^3} = \left(\dfrac{f(y)}{y}\right)^3 \to f'(0)^3$ as $y \to 0$.

Therefore, $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x) = f'(0)^3$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, since $f(0) = 0$, we have $f(x) = f'(0)^3x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Setting $x = 0$ gives us $f'(0) = f'(0)^3$, and thus, $f'(0) = -1, 0, 1$.

Since we are given $f'(0) \ge 0$, we must have $f'(0) = 0$ or $1$.

Thus, $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = x$, (both satisfy the constraints of the problem). So there are two possible values for $f(10)$, specifically, $f(10) = 0$ and $f(10) = 10$.

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution. +1